# Unicode in an Emacs regular expression

Tags: regex, emacs, unicode

I'm using emacs 24.

How can I replace all occurrences of the non-printable Unicode bidi character RTL, whose hexadecimal number is `202e`?  I want to replace it with the non-printable Unicode bidi character LTR, whose hexadecimal number is `202d`?

Could someone give me some guidance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Add the following piece of emacs Lisp code at the beginning of the buffer:

   `(while (re-search-forward "\u202e" nil t)

           (replace-match     "\u202d"))`
2. Place the cursor just after the last parenthesis and type <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-e</kbd> to execute the code.

Answer (score 6):

This requires `enable-recursive-minibuffers` is set to non-nil:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> replace-regexp <kbd>RET</kbd> <kbd><kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>8</kbd> <kbd>RET</kbd> 202e <kbd>RET</kbd></kbd> <kbd>RET</kbd> <kbd><kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>8</kbd> <kbd>RET</kbd> 202d <kbd>RET</kbd></kbd> <kbd>RET</kbd>

Comment: I didn't know about `C-x 8 RET`!

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this solution doesn't work. I still get the message "Replaced 0 occurrences".

Comment: @EvanAad: Is it possible the point was after the character to be replaced?

Comment: You can also pre-compose the strings in another buffer and then yank it into the minibuffer without changing `enable-recursive-minibuffers`.

Answer (score 1):

```
M-x replace-regexp RET \u202e RET \u202d
```

Comment: You'd think, wouldn't you!? Unfortunately, running this command on a file that consists of a single unicode character, whose hex number is 202e, yields the following message: "Replaced 0 occurrences"

Comment: This one doesn't work for me either, and I don't see why it should be expected to work.

Comment: Well, Elisp strings *do* have `\uXXXX` escape sequences for Unicode text.  So `(string-match-p "[\u4E00-\u9FFF]+" "中国")` returns `t`.  But minibuffer input strings don't go through that quoting process.

Answer (score 1):

Type the following:

```
M-% C-q 20056 RET RET C-q 20055 RET RET
```

<kbd>C-q</kbd> followed by an octal number and <kbd>RET</kbd> will insert the character represented by the octal number and discard the <kbd>RET</kbd>. To quickly convert hex to octal, type `#x202e` in a <kbd>M-:</kbd> prompt, which will print the resulting number in decimal, octal, and hex.

To enable easier input of decimal numbers, a la GTK's <kbd>C-S-u</kbd> binding, I use this in my `.emacs`:

```
(global-set-key [(control shift u)]
                (lambda ()
                  (interactive)
                  (let ((read-quoted-char-radix 16))
                    (call-interactively 'quoted-insert))))
```

Comment: Thanks, but i still get "Replaced 0 occurrences".

Comment: This does work for me. But I wonder why not just have `read-quoted-char-radix` always be 16?

Comment: @npostavs I've retried and it still doesn't work for me.